# Prepopulate dropdown select list in thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, select, thymeleaf, dropdown

I have user profile edit page and there is 3 dropdown lists with country, state and city. Country have not so many option(247) so I add them static in html other will get with AJAX from DB. I add on top of selected this code:

```
<option th:value="${theUser.country}" th:text="${theUser.country}"></option>
```

when I update some value on page to DB send numeric(value(id) of country/state/city) but I want name of the country. So when I am getting back and show on page not show number but countries/states/cities names.
How do it in thymeleaf or javascript.

I solve this with javascript:

```
var c ={};
$("#countryId").change(function () {
         c.countrytxt = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
```

do with state and city and before send to server with AJAX change saved value:

```
 formData.country = $('#countryId').val();
    formData.state = $('#stateId').val();
    formData.city = $('#cityId').val();
    formData.country = c.countrytxt;
    formData.state = c.statetxt;
    formData.city = c.citytxt;
```

Comment: When you state "show name and not number", do you want to show this in a `<div>` or a `<span>` as text? Or do you want have it selected in the `<option>` ?

Comment: I want it pre selected as text(as name) and may be user will want change his Country or State/City  and I want add State name to DB not value(value = number).